# When Click on given Id, Add a new Class Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given  HTML

```
<button id="showanswer">Show Answer</button>
```

When Click on This Frist Time Than add Class "one" AND When Return Click on it remove class "one"

how do this with javascript

```css
#showanswer {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 2px 5px 2px 25px;
color: #fff;
border: none;
font-size: 13px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #1bbc9b;
}
```

```html
<button id="showanswer">Show Answer</button>
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Consider using `classList.toggle('my-class-name')`?

Comment: sir thanks for replay we need this result <button class ="one" id="showanswer">Show Answer</button>

Comment: I always wonder why people spend time and effort to create such questions instead of googling it and find the answer probably in the first link in 2 minutes max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)
the class:

```js
document.getElementById("showanswer").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("one");
});
```

```css
#showanswer {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(https://static.javatpoint.com/images/eye-black.png) 1px 1px no-repeat;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 25px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0!important;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1bbc9b;
}
```

```html
<button id="showanswer">Show Answer</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the specific element in JavaScript using `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById` for example and then add the following:

```js
const showAnswerBtn = document.getElementById("showanswer");
showAnswerBtn.classList.toggle('one');
```